# Ubuntu16.04 run pcl in sublime text3, "fatal error: usr/include/pcl-1.7/pcl/point_types.h: No such file or directory"

Tags: c++, ubuntu, printer-control-language

I am new to C++ and `pcl`. I use Ubuntu 16.04. I just want to try `pcl` `PFH` estimation. And I need to use two files:`point_types.h` and `features/pfh.h`.
I included them at the top of my `.cpp` file:

```
"include usr/include/pcl-1.7/pcl/point_types.h"
"include usr/include/pcl-1.7/pcl/features/pfh.h"
```

There is an error fatal error:

> usr/include/pcl-1.7/pcl/point_types.h: No such file or directory

Why is that?
Very grateful!

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the `pcl` library is installed or not by using the below command.

```
ldconfig -p | grep libpcl
```

If you couldn't find anything then install it via [PCL PPA](http://www.pointclouds.org/downloads/linux.html)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:v-launchpad-jochen-sprickerhof-de/pcl
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libpcl-all-dev
```

Comment: HI, I checked in terminal and several .so files appeared with the path "usr/lib/x86-64-linux-gnu" And my .h files are in "usr/include/pcl-1.7/pcl" Is that OK? Very grateful!

Comment: Try `/` before `usr/include` i.e `/usr/include/`

Comment: I tried it and the previous error was solved but there is a new silimilar one. The project can find point_types.h and pfh.h now, but beacuse the point_types.h itself calls anoher .h file which is in usr/include/pcl-1.7/pcl The error becomes pcl/pcl_macros.h: No such file or directory . How could I add the pcl path to the whole project to avoid this kind of error?Thanks a lot!@jblixr

Comment: Include header search path as `-I/` for compiling, i.e `g++ -I/ yourfile.cpp`

Comment: So just add -I/usr/include/pcl-1.7/pcl  in the top of my cpp file in sublime text? The system seems to ignore the -I line. Could you explain more on how to do with -I flag? Sorry I really know nothing about C++ at this time...Very grateful!@jblixr